# Sum elements of the array based on index position, preferable with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have an array

```
int number = {3 ,5 ,2};
```

I know

```
number.Sum() = 10
```

and

```
number.Select(x=> sum+x) => {3, 8, 10}
```

I am looking for a way given a index to return the sum of the elements from index i to N

Example:

```
Sum(0) = 10
Sum(1) = 7
Sum(2) = 2
```

I can easily do it with a loop but I was wondering if there was a one-statement Linq that could be used.

Comment: `number.Skip(n + 1).Sum()` perhaps may work (+1 if you want to use index value, Index 0 would become Skip(1))

Comment: number.Select(x=> sum+x) => {3, 8, 10} when i tried that, visual studio says that the name sum does not exist in the current context - any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With i the number of elements you want to skip:

> number.Skip(i).Sum();